# Inset data in firebase realtime database with react-native

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtime Database in my react-native project. I want to save the data in below formate

```
Images
Category 1
Image: 
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgA...",
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgA..."
Category 2
Image: 
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgA..."
```

I want to store data depend upon categories. if I select category 1 the data is overwriting the old once, but I want to add without overwriting the previous data.
Is it possible to do so?

sample code

```
firebase.database().ref('Images/'+this.state.selectedValue).set({
    Image: this.state.imageSource,
  }).then(() =>{
    alert('saved')
  }).catch((error) =>{
  alert(JSON.stringify(error))
})
```

Comment: can I have your data format

Comment: Images:{
Category 1:[
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgA...",
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgA..."
],
Category 2:[
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgA..." 
]
}

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the new data to the old key so it is replacing it. You need to add a new key for every object like given below.

```
Images:{ 

Category 1:[{image1: "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAA..."},image2:{"jmehyrjwrjewrghwe"} ], 
Category 2:[ "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgA..." ],image2:{"jmehyrjwrjewrghwe"} }
```

Then it will work